# Make Bricks Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this question:

> We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a
>   number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each).
>   Return True if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the
>   given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done
>   without any loops.
>
> ```
> make_bricks(3, 1, 8) → True
> make_bricks(3, 1, 9) → False
> make_bricks(3, 2, 10) → True
> ```
>
> — [codingbat.com](https://codingbat.com/prob/p118406)

For that, I made this code:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
      tam = small + big*5
      ex_gran = goal - small

      if goal <= small:
        return True
      elif ex_gran > big*5: 
        return False
      elif ex_gran <= big * 5 and (ex_gran % 5 <= small) :
        return True
      else:
        return False
```

And this is the result os the tests:

```
Expected    Run     
make_bricks(3, 1, 8) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(3, 1, 9) → False    False   OK  
make_bricks(3, 2, 10) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(3, 2, 8) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(3, 2, 9) → False    True    X   
make_bricks(6, 1, 11) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(6, 0, 11) → False   False   OK  
make_bricks(1, 4, 11) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(0, 3, 10) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(1, 4, 12) → False   True    X   
make_bricks(3, 1, 7) → True False   X   
make_bricks(1, 1, 7) → False    False   OK  
make_bricks(2, 1, 7) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(7, 1, 11) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(7, 1, 8) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(7, 1, 13) → False   False   OK  
make_bricks(43, 1, 46) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(40, 1, 46) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(40, 2, 47) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(40, 2, 50) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(40, 2, 52) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(22, 2, 33) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(0, 2, 10) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(1000000, 1000, 1000100) → True  True    OK  
make_bricks(2, 1000000, 100003) → False True    X   
make_bricks(20, 0, 19) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(20, 0, 21) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(20, 4, 51) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(20, 4, 39) → True   True    OK
```

Only 4 of them was wrong, but I still can't figure it out the error.

What is wrong?

Comment: One mistake is that in `ex_gran = goal - small` you may use up all or too many small bricks to fill the goal but in `ex_gran % 5 <= small` you assume that you have all smalls available yet to fill the missing gap in `ex_gran`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is simple :) it lies on line 16. Although the code could be shorten a lot.

First if all, notice that condition `ex_gran <= big * 5` is irrelevant since the conditional before was already false (`elif ex_gran > big*5:`)  and we are assuming small, big and goal are all integers, so you can take that away from the code. (Althogh this is not what is bringing troubles to the code, that's more of a style remark).

Trouble is generated by this conditional: `(ex_gran % 5 <= small)`.

As I understand, in the example `make_bricks(1, 4, 12)` your code returns `True` when it should return `False`. What happens is that the code checks whether `(12 - 1) <= 4*5` which is `True`, and if `(12 - 1) % 5 <= 1` which is also `True` and returns `True` in line 18 because of this.

Let's "fix" the code. Remember that from math we know there are integers m and r such that `goal = 5*m + r` (moreover `r = goal % 5`). After we know `(goal-small) <= big*5` (from false evaluation in line 12) we have two cases:

Case 1: `(goal - small) = big*5`, which implies `goal = big*5 + small` and so we should return `True`.

Case 2: `(goal - small) < big*5`, then we know `goal < big*5 + small`. Here you should check whether `(goal % 5) <= small`. If this is false, then we can't arrange the bricks to obtain the goal length (since we don't have enough 1s to fill the residual, as in the example above). Otherwise, you should return `True`, since we have enough bricks to surpass the goal length and enough 1s to fill the residual.

Your code ends up looking like this (I took the liberty of renaming the variables):

```
def make_bricks(small_bricks, big_bricks, goal):

  if ( (5*big_bricks + small_bricks) < goal ):  #we can't reach the length

    return False

  elif  (small_bricks < (goal%5)) :   #we can surpass the length but we don't have 
                                      #enough 1s to fill goal's residual w.r.t. 5 div
    return False

  else:      #We can reach the length and have enough 1s to fill residual

    return True
```

notice I took away some case `goal <= small` as it's not needed here.

Answer (score 3):

Try first to use as many big bricks as possible, then complete with the small ones. Note that this works because the size of the big ones is a multiple of the size of the small ones, you would need another approach if the sizes were for example 2 and 5.

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    max_big = goal // 5  # max number of big we can use
    nb_big = min(big,  max_big)  # big ones we really use
    return small >= goal - 5 * nb_big  # True if we have enough small ones to complete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# This code works with those 3 tests but got some other one # wrong can some help fixed it?


def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
     big = big * 5
     if small == goal or big == goal:
          return true
      elif small + big == goal or big - small == goal:
            return True
      else:
           return False


print(make_bricks(3, 1, 8))  # → True
print(make_bricks(3, 1, 9))  # → False
print(make_bricks(3, 2, 10))  # → True
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  total_bricks = (1 * small) + (5 * big)
  if total_bricks >= goal:
    if goal%5 == 0:
      if goal/5 <= goal:
        x = True
    elif goal%5 <= small:
        x = True
    else:
      x = False
  else:
    x = False
  return x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient way but it will work..
Probably Not the most Readable

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  
  if (big is not 0 and (big*5+small*1 > goal) and goal % 5 <= small) or goal < small or big*5+small*1 == goal:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    return small >= goal - 5*min(goal//5,big)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 